# How to launch activity from notification such that it can't be navigated back to?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to launch an activity when a notification is clicked.

The Activity launched is a standalone activity and can not be opened from any other flow from the app itself. I need to ensure that no one can navigate back to this activity once it is destroyed.

Currently i am using the following configuration:

```
    <activity android:name=".Activities.SingleRestaurantOfferActivity"
        android:taskAffinity=".Activities.SingleRestaurantOfferActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"/>
```

And I am launching this activity with the intents

```
    FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Now when the acitivity is created (first notification click), it creates a new task and as per my understanding, if another notification is clicked, since the task will be existing, it will clear the task and re launch the new activity with the new intent. Is my understanding correct?

If the app is open. Then the user clicks on the notification and launches the activity. Now the home button is pressed. What will happen to the notification activity? The recents screen will only show the actual app task and not the notification activity task, will the notification activity be destroyed eventually or will it leak memory?

Please guide me as to how i should approach this. The official android guide also uses launchMode:singleTask, do i need to use that as well?

Comment: I don't completely understand your goals, but you might also want to experiment with the flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY.

Comment: I think your approach is good. I am not sure if your excluded from recent activity would leak memory or not but to ensure that it doesn't you can call finish() in your onPause() of that activity. I don't think you need to set launchMode as singleTask if you are already launching this activity with NEW_TASK and CLEAR_TASK flags .

Comment: @albert_braun .... Ty just added the noHistory so that it eventually does end up being killed. Exclude from recents was already there :)

Comment: @rohan bhatia... Thanks man :) i added noHistory flag and now onDestroy gets called as soon as i navigate away from the activity. Works out the same as your approach.

Comment: @Kushan glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here so that anyone who faces a similar issue gets an idea as to what they can do.

Steps to follow are:

1) In the manifest of the required activity, add the following:

```
android:taskAffinity = "com.yourpackage.youractivity"
This ensures that this activity has a seperate task affinity as compared to the default affinity. This will come into picture when excludeFromRecents is added.

android:excludeFromRecents = "true"
This flag tells android that the task associated with the given activity should not be shown in recents screen. If we had not added the taskAffinity explicitly, this would have meant that the whole application would not show in the recents screen which would be irritating. adding the task affinity will only hide the task of the required activity from recents

android:noHistory = "true"
I am not sure if this is necessarily needed. I added it to ensure that as soon as the user navigates away from the activity in any way ... eg home button, it will kill the activity using onDestroy. Also exclude from recents will prevent it from showing in the recents screen.
```

2) Now comes the part of intent flags to launch the activity:

I have used the flags:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK :
This flag along with the taskAffinity will create a new task for the activity if the task is not already created with the same affinity. Then it will place the activity at the root of this new task. If the task already exists, it will be brought to front and the new intent will be delivered to the activity in onNewIntent() method. I wanted the activity to get fully recreated so i added the other flag below.

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK:
This flag clears the task and kills all the activities in it. Then it adds the new intended activity at the root of the task. This will ensure in my case that the activity gets fully destroyed and recreated from scratch. You might not need this in your case. CLEAR_TOP with standard launch mode will also almost do the same thing but that's a whole different scenario.
```

Hope this helps people creating standalone activities which don't merge directly into app flows.